# Pytorch: Freeze layer and make layer's gradients as 0's

Tags: python, pytorch

What's the correct way to set a pytorch neural network to be false?

(1) In this post: [https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~lczhang/321/lec/input_notes.html](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Elczhang/321/lec/input_notes.html), they set model.requires_grad=False. However, when I check

```
for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    print(name, param.requires_grad)
```

I got all True. And all param.grad are not 0's.

(2) If I do set param.requires_grad=False, I will get all param.grad as `None`

What I am trying to do is the same with the link in (1). However, the gradients are not expected.